# How to get actual font name from font file using typscript

Tags: javascript, typescript, fonts

Currently I am working on one project in which, I need to generate font preview image by uploading font file.

And I want to make image like below (transparent png with font name) :

[image]

but problem is that I Don't know, how to get original font name (not a file name), so that I set that name as text and apply that font and make image.

Is there any way to get all data of any font file using typescript ?

Please help me.

Comment: How are the fonts loaded into the `document`?

Comment: This is using below code :

var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var junction_font = new FontFace('tmp', reader.result);
            junction_font.load().then(function (loaded_face) {
                document['fonts'].add(loaded_face);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        };

Comment: Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.com or gist https://gist.github.com which includes the font file?

Comment: I am creating fiddle for you, please wait.

Comment: Not sure if jsfiddle is able to create and store entire files, though plnkr does have that functionality at the left panel

Comment: This is like for fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/xhty3n6e/11/

Comment: you can choose any font file. and you will see that that font is loaded  in dom and set to <p> element

Comment: This is new fiddle for load google font dynamically. no need to upload static font file : https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/xvpk0rnm/2

Comment: I have no idea how to use plunkr and gist. so I have create fiddle.

Comment: I just want to read only original name of font from font file when user choose font file.

Comment: Only getting error when trying to load the font

Comment: in which fiddle ( first ) ?

Comment: Yes. The second produces expected result. The user provides the name of the font, correct?

Comment: No, user upload only font file, we detect that which font user have uploaded.

Comment: At the first parameter to `FontFace()`. Do you have a link to `.woff2` of `Roboto`?

Comment: flow of user uploaded font is like Below :

1) user select font file from their pc
2) we detect original name of font and create preview image using canvas
3) upload font file and preview image on server.
4) show image in font dropdown 
5) when user select that font, we load font file dynamically like in second fiddle

Comment: in second fiddle, I just want to show you how to load font dynamically with example of google font.

Comment: In my flow of font uploading, font path is come from my server.

Comment: Does not appear to be possible without parsing binary file https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188567/discussion-between-mayur-kukadiya-and-guest271314).

Comment: Sorry, ~Does not appear to be possible without parsing binary file w3.org/TR/WOFF2~ I don't understand what you want to say ?

Comment: Read the specification for the bytes to parse. Appears to be the first 48

Comment: could you please make fiddle that return font name when user select font file ?

Comment: Attempting to parse the file, to get the name of the font, if possible. Reading the specification should be helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will try it.